# RethinkDB: trouble with basic JavaScript example

Tags: javascript, timeout, rethinkdb

I have the server running on port `8080`, I can see the web interface...

When I try to run [this example](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/install-drivers/javascript/) from command line, like this: `node test.js` (node version: `4.1.0`), I get:

```
playground/rethink/node_modules/rethinkdb/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:43
    fn = function () { throw arg; };
                       ^
ReqlTimeoutError: Could not connect to localhost:8080, operation timed out.
```

Why?

I installed RethinkDB via Homebrew and I'm on Mavericks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you changed the port number in the demo code to 8080?

`r.connect({ host: 'localhost', port: 28015 }, ...`

don't do that.

Port 8080 is reserved for http administrative connections, while client driver connections go through port 28015. Leave it at port 28015 and try it again.

Comment: By the way regarding ports... I added `http-port=8090` to `/etc/rethinkdb.conf` and just upgraded rethinkdb and it doesn't read that setting anymore.. admin is at `8080` and that clashes with a lot of other things